# node: peer dependency for react-scripts

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a following error from the npm install after i upgrade to react-script 5.0.0.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @craco/craco@6.4.5
npm ERR! Found: react-scripts@5.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"^5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-scripts@"^4.0.0" from @craco/craco@6.4.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@craco/craco
npm ERR!   dev @craco/craco@"^6.4.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @craco/craco@"^6.0.0" from craco-less@1.20.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/craco-less
npm ERR!     dev craco-less@"^1.20.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-scripts@4.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   peer react-scripts@"^4.0.0" from @craco/craco@6.4.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@craco/craco
npm ERR!     dev @craco/craco@"^6.4.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @craco/craco@"^6.0.0" from craco-less@1.20.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/craco-less
npm ERR!       dev craco-less@"^1.20.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
```

Is there a way to resolve this error?